# pip not working after installing python3 on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

I installed python3 from the official website and then installed jupyter notebook. While trying to run jupyter notebook, I was getting a "command not found" error.

I found [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/89) and followed the instructions to delete python3 and reinstall using Homebrew instead (I've used Homebrew before).

When trying `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` i get a "No module named pip" error. My `/usr/local/bin/` file shows pip, pip2, pip2.7, pip3, pip3.6.

I have a feeling my pip is not associated with the python3 that I installed using Homebrew. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound yes I tried pip3 and got the same error. Although I can see it in the usr/local/bin folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way is a pretty fool-proof way to install pip for a specific python interpreter, when you have a big mess of them on the machine:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > /tmp/get_pip.py
$ my_python_interpreter /tmp/get_pip.py
```

Then:

```
$ my_python_interpreter -m pip install some_dist
```