# How can an old setuptools be upgraded if the old version encounters an error when trying to upgrade itself?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I appear to have encountered the following error by using an older version of setuptools with Python 3:

```
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885
```

How can I actually advance to a newer version to escape this error? It's a bit of a catch 22.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Answer (score 1):

Download [the source distribution](https://pypi.python.org/packages/e0/02/2b14188e06ddf61e5b462e216b15d893e8472fca28b1b0c5d9272ad7e87c/setuptools-38.5.2.zip#md5=b4c7f29c8079bdf2f0f355cdcd999e69), unpack it, and install it like this:

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/e0/02/2b14188e06ddf61e5b462e216b15d893e8472fca28b1b0c5d9272ad7e87c/setuptools-38.5.2.zip
$ unzip setuptools-38.5.2.zip
$ cd setuptools-38.5.2
$ python3 bootstrap.py
```

Note: neither `pip` nor `wheel` are necessary to install `setuptools`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. When I run `sudo python3 bootstrap.py` setuptools appears to install, but when I then try to run pip I encounter the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Well, you want to install for your user, not for root.  So you probably shouldn't be using `sudo` in the first place, you should be using a virtual environment or installing to [the user site](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/).

Comment: To bootstrap `pip`, see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48550868/674039).